# Charls Proxy Method Filtering

Tags: charles-proxy

Is it possible to set a filter for request for certain type of method like GET, POST, OPTIONS?
I am using Map Local or Map Remote and I am interested in mapping only GET request. Unfortunately, my browser also sends request with method OPTIONS that have exactly same address.